# attr.ib ignores value parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-attrs

[`attr.ib`](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/api.html#attr.ib) takes a `repr` argument that may be a bool or callable.

> To override how the attribute value is formatted, pass a callable that takes a single value and returns a string. Note that the resulting string is used as-is, i.e. it will be used directly instead of calling `repr()` (the default).

That does not appear to be the case when passing `datetime.datetime.fromisoformat()`:

```
import datetime
import attr

@attr.s
class Test(object):
    foo: str = attr.ib()
    dt: datetime.datetime = attr.ib(repr=datetime.datetime.isoformat)
```

Result:

```
>>> t = Test(foo='bar', dt=datetime.datetime.utcnow())                                                                                                                                                                                                       
>>> t                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Test(foo='bar', dt=datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 31, 17, 59, 34, 603971))
```

Expected:

```
Test(foo='bar', dt='2019-10-31T17:59:34.603971')
```

In fact, it looks like any parameter is ignored.  Here is a slight modification of the example from the attr docs:

```
>>> @attr.s 
... class C(object): 
...     user = attr.ib() 
...     password = attr.ib(repr=lambda value: value[:2]) 
...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
>>> C("me", "s3kr3t")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
C(user='me', password='s3kr3t')
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `attrs` installation must be too old.  Your code works perfectly with `attrs` 19.3:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import attr
>>>
>>> @attr.s
... class Test(object):
...     foo: str = attr.ib()
...     dt: datetime.datetime = attr.ib(repr=datetime.datetime.isoformat)
...
>>> Test(foo='bar', dt=datetime.datetime.utcnow())
Test(foo='bar', dt=2019-11-01T05:40:59.745157)
```

You can check you `attrs`'s version using:

```
>>> attr.__version__
'19.3.0'
```

The repr feature has been added in 19.2.0 that was released only a month ago on 2019-10-01.

Comment: Yep, I'm in an env that has attrs==18.2.0 so that could very well be the case.